# Calculating Datum Corrections to Overlay pre-NAD27 USGS Maps?

Tags: datum, geodesy, historical-imagery

I am working with some older (*ca.* 1900) USGS Topographic Maps. These Raster maps are georeferenced  with a CRS of `NAD27` and `poly` projection (polyconic). However, they are offset and require easting/northing corrections in the georeferenced source data to overlay on modern maps.

On some maps, in the 1920's, Someone had calculated these offsets for the original editions, perhaps to celebrate the creation of `NAD27`, who knows.

I am looking for some pointers on how that was done.

**I want to know if there is a way to calculate this correction generally/automatically.** , or alternatively if there is a standard set of datums to use to account for the easting/northing correction in these old maps.

---

### Example

[San Francisco 1916 15' x 15', Warning >10MB](https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/StagedProducts/Maps/HistoricalTopo/2/14680/4989115.pdf)

This source data is already referenced to NAD27, the CRS as encoded in the file is usually interpreted by QGIS as something like

```
+proj=poly +lat_0=37.75 +lon_0=-122.375 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD27 +units=m +no_defs
```

While the projection is good, it is not perfectly correct, when used as-is the data is quite offset

[image]

Luckily, on some editions the following can be found

[image]

Which I Interpret as Easting and Northing corrections to the CRS definition.

```
+proj=poly +lat_0=37.75 +lon_0=-122.375 +x_0=-97.536 +y_0=-201.168 +datum=NAD27 +units=m +no_defs
```

The result is quite good.

[image]

Additionally, I have also encountered the following note

[image]

By extracting the measured projected distance (in QGIS) between the solid frame and the dashed frame

[image]

I can extract `x_0` and `y_0` and use it like above

Sometimes, however nothing is provided and I calculate this offset by hand by doing some projected distance measurements of good reference points.

In all cases its a labor intensive process.

---

### Last Word

Someone has calculated these offsets before, so I am looking for some pointers on how that was done.

Comment: It appears to be inaccessible now (Monday, Nov 13 2017) but [NADCON 5.0](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NADCON5/index.shtml) can convert from NAD27 to older datums. That's a new capability at version 5.

Comment: The link to NADCON 5.0 should work now (later on Monday, Nov 13 2017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to NAD27 / North American Datum of 1927, US maps used the US standard datum AKA USSD. Starting at NADCON 5.0, the National Geodetic Survey (NGS) has started supporting transformations to and from USSD. You can access the Coordinate Conversion tool online, [here](https://beta.ngs.noaa.gov/gtkweb/).

That link goes to a beta version of the tool. At some point, the online tool will move out of beta (NADCON 5.0 has already been declared out-of-beta). If the link stops working or doesn't redirect properly, try starting at the main page, http://www.ngs.noaa.gov, and hover over Tools in the header and select "Datum Transformations (NADCON)" in the list.

The homepage for [NADCON 5.0](https://www.ngs.noaa.gov/NADCON5/index.shtml) includes a link to a PDF that gives more details on the supported datums.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up. [NADCON provides an ftp repository](ftp://ftp.ngs.noaa.gov/pub/nadcon5/20160901release/), with what appears to be the raw tools used to provide this service, have you ever tried or had success using these tools locally instead of as a web service?

Comment: That's great! Good going!